# raspberry pi application menu icon restore?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, raspi-config

accidentally deleted the red rasberry app menu icon from toolbar. I purchased a new SD preloaded and it automatically updated to latest rasbian and while trying to restore default monitor settings after initially loving the LoveRPi easy SD card Im now lost with a couple problems I have no idea to remedy. Where I went wrong initially was System Configuration trying different settings and the choices I mistakenly selected Overscan enable and Pixel Doubling enable have me now unable to disable because I cant get the cursur arrow to the bottom of the window disappeared below the screen despite changing to small monitor default which helped but all the icons and windows are HUGE now and the Rasberry Pi Configuration System wont allow resize I can only un/decorate the blue header which then shows the pixel doubling when the window is lessened in height but no ok or apply whatever the last before reboot I cant see it and cant effect it so Im stuck with giant everything and hoping Im not out the $46 for a new SD card that I didnt have the good sense to copy beforehand. Yes and the red Rasberry menu app shortcut icon I somehow also deleted from the toolbar messing about trying to get back to the clean interface I was so happy to see. Help Please!

Answer (score 1):

To add the menu icon (Raspberry icon) back onto the task bar:

[image]

Right click on the task bar, select 'Add / Remove Panel Items':
[image]

Click the 'Add' button:
[image]

Scroll down to the 'Menu' panel item, click 'Add':
[image]

Use 'Up' and 'Down' buttons to position the menu icon at the far left of the taskbar:
[image]

[image]

To change the menu icon to the raspberry pi logo, right click the menu icon, select 'Menu Settings':
[image]

Set the icon path and file to /usr/share/raspberrypi-artwork/launch.png:
[image]

Done:

[image]

Comment: That answer works up to setting the icon path. An icon at '/usr/share/raspberrypi-artwork/launch.png' exists on my Pi 2 B with Raspbian 11 (bullseye), but no icon appears on the menu. To see the raspberry icon I had to enter just 'start-here' with padding 4 when setting the icon path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyboard to navigate the Raspberry Pi menu, and the preferences menu. Pressing the supper key (also known as the logo key or Windows key) should open the menu. If that does not work, pressing `ctrl-alt-T` will open the terminal. Pixel doubling can be turned off from `raspi-config`>`Advanced`. Hope that helps.
[image: raspi-config]
[image: raspi-config>advanced]